# MSSQL Query optimization

Tags: sql-server

MSSQL, i need to pass set of parameters for a query... is there any way i can do it in one shot!

I have 2 data sources CD and VD. 
i have data for products: Product A,B,C... in Data source CD
i have data for products: Product 1,2,3... in Data source VD

ProductA is same as Product1
ProductB is same as Product2
I need the matching data for a ProductA/1,ProductB/2.. from those 2 different sources
If they had same product names in both the sources i could group by Product name, But they have different Product names.

Query 1:

```
SELECT CD.Description,Count(DISTINCT CD.TweetId) AS MatchingCount
FROM   Result_Table_CSData CD
       INNER JOIN Result_Table_VData VD
               ON CD.TweetId = VD.TweetID
                  AND CD.Description = 'Product1'
                  AND VD.Description = 'ProductA'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT CD.Description,Count(DISTINCT CD.TweetId) AS MatchingCount
FROM   Result_Table_CData CD
       INNER JOIN Result_Table_VData VD
               ON CD.TweetId = VD.TweetID
                  AND CD.Description = 'Product2'
                  AND VD.Description = 'ProductB'
```

I have 100 of products in Description column of both the tables... please suggest a way so that i can run single query ins-ted running one query for each product.

Comment: What would be the desired output of the single query?   How will you be passing the multiple parameters from your app?

Comment: Edited my question hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Is it an ad hoc query or a stored procedure? Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: You could use a procedure and pass the product name as parameter(I guess the parameter is the product name)

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a query that allows you to link Product1 with ProductA, but as you said, there is no such link.  I don't know how feasible this is, but it seems like you are going to have to create that link by creating a table that contains the product name/ID from source CD and the corresponding product name/ID from source VD.

```
CDDesc    VDDesc
--------- --------
Product1  ProductA
Product2  ProductB
```

The query would then be

```
SELECT CD.Description,Count(DISTINCT CD.TweetId) AS MatchingCount
FROM   Result_Table_CSData CD
INNER JOIN SourceLink SL ON (CD.Description = SL.CDDesc)
INNER JOIN Result_Table_VData VD
           ON CD.TweetId = VD.TweetID
           AND (SL.VDDesc = VD.Description)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CD.Description,(Count(DISTINCT CD.TweetId) + Count(DISTINCT VD.TweetId)) AS MatchingCount
FROM   Result_Table_CSData CD
       INNER JOIN Result_Table_VData VD
               ON CD.TweetId = VD.TweetID
 AND charindex(REPLACE(VD.Description,'PRODUCT',''),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')=CAST(REPLACE(CD.Description,'PRODUCT','') AS INT) GROUP BY CD.Description,VD.Description
```

Comment: have not tried query but idea is this only ... enjoy

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 SELECT 
  CD.Description
,Count(CD.TweetId) Over (Partition CD.Description ,VD.Description ,  CD.TweetId)  AS MatchingCount
FROM   Result_Table_CSData CD
cross apply (select VD.Description from Result_Table_VData VD where CD.TweetId = VD.TweetID AND VD.Description in ('ProductA','ProductB') ) VD
where CD.Description in ('Product1','Product2')
```

this should get you the required!